# 'Best practices' for making Stim run as fast as possible?

Tags: programming, error-correction, simulation, stim

I'm currently testing out an error-correction surface code circuit in [Stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim).

I've tried a 19x19 surface code over 10k rounds of syndrome extraction sampled 256 times, and this takes about 165 seconds.  This comes out to roughly ~100s of nanoseconds per measurement, which is not as fast as I'd like.

I was wondering if there are 'best practices' for making circuits as fast as possible in Stim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Output format**: Use a bit packed output format that has 8 results per byte instead of 1. In the python bindings, this means calling `sample_bit_packed` instead of `sample`. From the command line, this means specifying `--out_format=b8`. You're paying ~5x performance if you're using a non-bit packed output.

   From the command line, for detection events, you can also consider sparse output formats like `--out_format=r8` where each byte tells you the number of 0 results until the next 1 (except 0xFF used for long runs of zeros). For error rates below 0.1% this can easily be 10x less data output.
2. **Sample size**: Take a number of samples that's a multiple of 256. Stim internally pads the number of samples up to a multiple of 256, because it operates simultaneously across batches using 256 bit wide AVX instructions. It does this even if you ask for 2 samples, and the other 254 are going to be discarded.
3. **Command Line Tool**: Consider using the command line tool instead of the python bindings. The python bindings add overhead (extra data copying), and are currently less flexible than the command line tool. You're paying ~2x performance to use stim via python.

   Note that when you print a `stim.Circuit` in python, the result is text that the command line tool can parse to get that exact same circuit, so it's quite easy to generate your circuit files from python by making the circuit as usual and printing it to a file.

   An example where the command line tool is currently *necessary* is if your circuit is really big, with hundreds of billions of bits of data coming out. The command line tool will notice the size and automatically switch from buffering all results in memory to streaming results to disk. The python bindings are not currently capable of doing this, because they return the results as a numpy array; in memory. Speaking from personal experience, streaming the results from huge circuits can be the difference between things working and watching helplessly as your computer completely freezes due to madly swapping memory to and from disk.
4. **REPEAT block**: Use the `REPEAT` block instead of explicitly repeating things. If you have a circuit with a hundred thousand rounds of the same operations, putting them inside a `REPEAT 100000 { ... }` block instead of actually repeating them a hundred thousand times will reduce memory usage and hugely reduce parsing time.

   In the python bindings, you can create a repeat block by multiplying the circuit by an integer. So create a `stim.Circuit` containing the body of the loop, then do `full_circuit += loop_body * 100000`.
5. **Grouping operations**: Have your measurements come in groups and your resets come in groups, without other operations or noise in between. For example, this:

   ```
    M 0
    M 1
    M 2
    X_ERROR(0.01) 0
    X_ERROR(0.01) 1
    X_ERROR(0.01) 2
   ```

   happens to be faster than this:

   ```
    M 0
    X_ERROR(0.01) 0
    M 1
    X_ERROR(0.01) 1
    M 2
    X_ERROR(0.01) 2
   ```

   This is because (currently) stim temporarily transposes the entire stabilizer tableau when performing a measurement, but avoids re-transposing for adjacent measurements.

   It's certainly possible for stim to be made smarter here, to move measurements around so more can be fused or to partially transpose the tableau as required, but currently it's not that smart.

   Grouping measurements isn't relevant if you're sampling detection events or specify `--frame0`, because those modes bypass the stabilizer tableau simulation step where the transposing occurs. But you never know when you'll later want raw measurements...

   Another, more minor, benefit of grouping operations of the same type is that a noisy operation with many targets can have their "did the error happen" bits generated together in an efficient way. But if you're asking for hundreds or thousands of samples then you're already getting most of that benefit.

Comment: Excellent!  This brings me down to about ~4 ns per measurement, which is just what I needed.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Is it possible to get a bit packed output when using [sinter](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/08f968e4201f2f5238f6923a8f2583f0ea247a22/glue/sample/README.md#sinter-fast-qec-sampling) to sample?

Comment: Would it also make it faster to specify TMPDIR as RAM?

Comment: @drumadoir sinter already internally uses bit packed formats. The current stable version does get bottlenecked on disk, but that was to avoid thrashing the system by using too much memory storing huge batches of shots to amortize decoder configuration. This is properly fixed in the latest dev version, where it can keep the configured decoder around to stream shots through instead of recreating it each time.